# JSF play video file

Tags: jsf, video, desktop-application

I want to play a video file from my web app. I use JSF. I want to know how we can open the video file with the help of any video player installed in the client's system. I know how to open a pdf file the same way. But I want to know how to open a video file.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf pick one ...

Answer (score 6):

There's no standard JSF component for this. It's however not different from as you would do in plain HTML. Just drop the video file in public webcontent (so that it's reachable by an URL) and use the HTML `<embed>` and/or the `<object>` element which points to the URL of the video file. That's basically all. Note that you can just use EL in template text. So e.g. `<embed src="#{bean.videoURL}">` would work perfectly fine, as long as it generates the HTML code the way you intend (open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* to see it).

The way how to create and parameterize the HTML `<embed>` or `<object>` tag in turn depends on the video format (MPEG, MOV, FLV, etc). You basically need to consult the documentation of the video format vendor for details how to use it. Since you didn't mention what format the video file is in, we can't help you further in detail. Googling the smart way should however yield sufficient examples. E.g. "[embed mpeg in html](http://google.com/search?q=embed%20mpeg%20in%20html)".

PrimeFaces has however a [`<p:media>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf) component which makes it all easier for developers who are lazy in Googling for examples and/or figuring the browser specific inconsitenties ;) It'll outright generate the right HTML code necessary for the provided video format.

#### See also:

- [How to stream audio/video files such as MP3, MP4, AVI, etc using a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588149/how-to-stream-audio-video-files-such-as-mp3-mp4-avi-etc-using-a-servlet)

Answer (score 2):

This works in browsers those support HTML5.

```
<video controls="controls">
  <source src="resources/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```